# How to duplicate entry to catch and correct syntax for Insert

Tags: java, mysql

I Have these codes and I want to catch the Duplicate entry violation error. I don't know how to catch it to make it work. I want to systemout("Name already existing") if there is already name similar to the one he inputed.

this is my code.

```
try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(mydb);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ps.setString(1, name());
        ps.setInt(2, contactnumber());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
} catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Other one is that What is the correct syntax for this?

```
String sql = "SELECT name,contact number from contactlist
              WHERE name like '%?%' OR  contact '?';
```

Comment: You have a blank in your column name `contact number` is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: sorry no space. its only typo error.

Answer (score 1):

```
       catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ce) {
           systemout("Name already existing")
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Error it says.  "ConstraintViolationException cannot be resolve to a type"

Answer (score 0):

For second part (select), use following code:

```
String sql = "SELECT name,contact number from contactlist
          WHERE name like ? OR  contact ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, "%<anything>%");
stmt.setString(2, "contact");
```